# Jenkins job to reset AWS password

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm very new to cloud and CI tools, so please help me to clear my doubts.
Does it possible to reset AWS Password every 20th day using a Jenkins job?
If so, what are the procedure to create the Jenkins job?

Comment: as a side note, you should protect your AWS login with multi factor authentication https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/ then you will not be able to code a job to do it

Comment: Which AWS password are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the first answer to get started quickly I'd suggest installing aws cli on Jenkins node and running the below simple command

```
aws iam change-password --old-password <value> --new-password <value>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can do it like this:

1. Create freestyle job on Jenkins.
2. Set build trigger to run every 20th day[image: build trigger]
3. Add build step that actually resets the password. You can use Windows batch command, powershell command or whatever type of script you want. I know that Powershell got AWS Toolset that could help you with that.